# MySQL to return only last date / time record

Tags: mysql

i have a table that has a serial number, date and time when that serial number was modified.  i would like to retrieve the latest time and date when that particular serial number was modified.  any suggestions?  the dates and times are on different columns.

thanks

Comment: What datatype are the date/time fields?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data and time columns are of types that MySQL knows how to sort correctly (i.e. `DATE` and `TIME` types), this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
ORDER BY date_col DESC, time_col DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how one can find the most recent record – can there be multiple rows with the same date and time ?
Is the serial number monotonically increasing or decreasing ?

Try using `ORDER BY` (`DESC` sorts from newest to oldest) and `LIMIT` to get what you want, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `date` DESC, `time`, `serial` DESC LIMIT 1
```